# Creating instance of virtual table in MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have dataset generated by some PHP shenanigans, which looks like this:

```
id  name   amount
1   Tonny  50 
3   Jenny  80
10  Mike   80
```

I would like to take advantage of the powerful SQL tools and use them to work with this data set, join some existing mysql tables to it and so on.

Now here is the caveat:
I do not want to actually save that data onto an HDD, like regular tables do, since its only purpose is to be displayed to the user once, and after each reload of the page it gets generated over again (with different data).

I know I can create a virtual table in mysql, where all data in it is lost upon reboot of the server, or the mysql engine, but that is not what I need, because the data in that table is "static" (all instances of the running php script see the same instance of mysql data), while i need to make an instance of that table.

To put it simply, if 10 people load that page at the exactly same time, then there will be 10 copies (instances ) of that virtual table, each instance of the running php script will have its own instance of the table with unique data.

Is this possible with mysql?

So far, the only solution I came up with, is to create a regular virtual table and then each php instance working with it locks it, until it's done working with it, then empties the table and unlocks it, so the next php instance waiting in line can have a turn. But this is very slow and not so great.

Comment: Have you looked at transactions? Open a transaction and then never commit it. It will be unique to the session and go away eventually.

Comment: Maybe use `MEMORY` engine https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html ?

Comment: Temporary tables (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) + (optional) MEMORY engine may be a solution. They are "virtual" per session. Persistent php mysql connection can become an obstacle though.